# como anidar 2 registro de una misma tabla

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Hola tengo un consulta es que tengo una tabla cursos donde cod_curso, cod_ramo, sección y nombre.
lo que tengo es un buscador(autocompletar) del nombre del curso eso me resulta bien, pero lo que necesito al momento de encontrar el curso me habilite todas las secciones del curso, ejemplo yo busco el curso CALCULO I y me tendría que habilitar un combobox con todas la secciones(1,2,3,4,5,6)

```html
 <?php
    require("conexion.php")
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <form action="" method="post">
  <div class="container" style="width:600px;">
   <br /><br />
   
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="sel1">Seleccione año de ingreso:</label>
           <select class="form-control" name="anio_ingreso" id="ua" placeholder="Ingrese unidad academica">
            <?php
                            
            $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT DISTINCT anio_ingreso FROM `alumnos` ORDER BY `anio_ingreso` ASC");
           
            while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            
            echo '<option value="">'.$valores[anio_ingreso].'</option>';
             
            }
    
            ?> 
      
           </select>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="sel1">Seleccione unidad acamdemica:</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="ua" id="ua" placeholder="Ingrese unidad academica">
        <?php
                            
        $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT DISTINCT ua FROM `alumnos` ORDER BY `ua` ASC");
           
         while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            
         echo '<option value="'.$valores[ua].'">'.$valores[ua].'</option>';
             
         }
    
        ?> 
      
   </select>
   </div>
   <br>
   
   <div class="form-group">
   <label>Seleccione Asignatura:</label>
   <input type="text" name="cursos" id="cursos" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" />
    
   </div>
   
   <div class="form-group">
   <label>Seleccione Seccion:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="seccion" id="seccion" placeholder="Ingrese unidad academica">
        <?php
                            
        $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT seccion FROM `cursos` WHERE nombre = '?????' ORDER BY `seccion` ASC");
           
         while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            
         echo '<option value="'.$valores[seccion].'">'.$valores[seccion].'</option>';
             
         }
    
        ?> 
      
   </select>
   </div>
   
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="sel1">Seleccione año:</label>
           <select class="form-control" name="" id="" placeholder="">
              <option value=2016>2016 
              <option value=2017>2017 
              <option value=2018>2018 
              <option value=2019>2019 
      
           </select>
   </div>
   
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="sel1">Seleccione semestre:</label>
           <select class="form-control" name="" id="" placeholder="">
              <option value=Primer>Primer 
              <option value=Segundo>Segundo

      
           </select>
   </div>
   
   
   </div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('#cursos').typeahead({
  source: function(query, result)
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"fetch.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{query:query},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
     result($.map(data, function(item){
      return item;
     }));
    }
   })
  }
 });
 
});
</script>
```

```html
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "encuesta1");
$request = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
$request = htmlspecialchars($request);
$query = "SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE nombre  LIKE '".$request."%' LIMIT 5";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$data = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  $data[] = $row["nombre"];
 }
 echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

[image: ejemplo cursos]

cualquier ayuda o orientación sera bienvenida

Comment: ¿La última imagen qué tabla es `cursos` o `secciones`?

Comment: hay una sola tabla cursos que tiene 3000 registros de cursos de una facultad y esa tiene cod_curso, cod_ramo, seccion y nombre, estos datos fueron recibidos en un json

Comment: Ya... pero si puedes modificar tu diseño deberías hacerlo. Por ejemplo, tienes una redundancia de datos horrible. Deberías tener una tabla **`cursos`** con las columnas `id_curso, cod_curso, nombre, cod_ramo...` una tabla **`secciones`** con las columnas `id_seccion, seccion`  y una tabla **`cursos_secciones`** con dos columnas: `id_curso, id_seccion` para introducir las secciones y cursos relacionados. Luego usas JOIN para obtener los datos que necesites.